# Limitations / Cons of editing an active workflow?

Tags: jira, workflow

I actually moved to **Jira** and to be honest, it is really helpful and effective tool. I wonder everything has limitations, What are the **limitations** in jira when an active workflow is being edited?
There has to be some things that the user should be careful about. Any guidance would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wel, I got this from a link.
If a workflow is active, you cannot edit the workflow name (only the description)
You cannot delete the workflow steps
A step associated status cannot be edited
You cannot add any new outgoing transition if a step has no outgoing transitions (Global transitions are not considered).
A step’s Step ID cannot be changed.
If any one can add anything on this, please go ahead